# ERROR AL PUBLICAR UNA APLICACIÓN WEBFORMS COMO AZURE APP SERVICE

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure

Tengo una aplicación hecha en asp .net webforms, que, hasta ahora, se ejecutaba directamente en el IIS de un servidor. Al publicarla como Azure App Service, en principio, todo va bien. Pero al ir a ejecutarla con la URL de Azure, da un error, aparentemente, porque falta alguna librería:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Datos' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

El caso es que, cuando publico en local, sí que está todo.

¿Qué debería hacer?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto. Por si a alguien le interesa, el problema era que el plan (no la suscripción) de Azure con que estaba probando sólo admite 32 bits y no permite cambiar a 64. Basta con cambiar a un plan que permita 64 y ya funciona.